# Pythonic way to perform urljoin operation on each value of a column in Pandas dataframe (Python 3.4)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have Pandas dataframe where one of the columns "url" contains a relative url path. The values in this column needs to be appended with the base url to be converted into absolute url.

I am sure looping through each row of the column is not the best approach. I am able to do this by using Lambdas operation. However the lambdas seem a bit magic for me and I am not so comfortable with it.

Can you recommmenda better way of doing this? Thanks.

```
    from urllib.parse import urljoin
    import pandas as pd
    .
    base_url = "http://www.website.com"
    .
    my_df["relatie_url"] = my_df["relatie_url"].map(lambda x : urljoin(base_url, x))
```

Comment: Note that if you have to perform `urljoin` then using `map` or `apply` would be fine here

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can just do:

```
my_df["relatie_url"] = base_url + my_df["relatie_url"]
```

This will be much quicker than calling `map`

Example:

```
In [12]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'site':['/home/index.html', '/images/src']})
df

Out[12]:
               site
0  /home/index.html
1       /images/src

In [13]:
base_url = "http://www.website.com"
df['site'] = base_url + df['site']
df

Out[13]:
                                     site
0  http://www.website.com/home/index.html
1       http://www.website.com/images/src
```

Comment: This is nice and simple. Thanks. Is there any disadvantage with this approach compared to urljoin, considering we are just doing string concatenation here?

Comment: For pure string concatenation, this will be vectorised, using `map` and `apply` this is just a `for` loop so this approach will be much faster for large datasets